# PHP Intervention Image Resize image to fit shortest side to aspect ratio

Tags: php, image-processing, image-resizing

How do I resize an image using [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) maintaining the aspect ratio but making the image's shortest side fit the desired resize ratio.

E.g. a 800x400 image resized to fit 100x100 will be resized to 200x100

I tried this:

```
$image->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

But it resizes the longest side to fit (e.g. 100x50).

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you need. Can you please be more clear: I have this, but I need this.

Comment: @PedroLobito if I `resize(100, 100)` an 800x400 image it resizes to to 100x50. I want it to resize to 200x100

Comment: Understood. I'll take a look

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set **width** as `null` :

```
$height = 100;
$image = Image::make('800x400.jpg')->resize(null, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$image->save('200X100.jpg', 60);
```

Programatically speaking, just find the larger side and set it to `null`, i.e:

```
$width = 100;
$height = 100;
$image = Image::make('400x800.png');
$image->width() > $image->height() ? $width=null : $height=null;
$image->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$image->save('100x200.jpg', 60);
```

Comment: Pedro, weight should probably be width.  Plus, you may consider adding "$constraint->upsize();"  into the function to prevent upsizing.